# Is default stringstream formatting the same as snprintf's?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, stringstream, printf

I'm looking to replace some snprintf calls with stringstreams.  I need to ensure the output is identical.

given `long l = some_input_var;`

do

```
std::ostringstream str;
str << l;
return str.str();
```

and

```
buf str[24];
snprintf(str, 24, "%ld", l);
return std::string(str);
```

return identical strings?

What about for `int` and `"%d"` or  `double` and `"%f"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But it's a long story: iostreams formatting works via the stream's codec's formatting facet. The details are fairly involved; see C++11 27.7. The default facet's conversion uses `sprintf` for input formatting and the `strtoull`-type functions for output; see 22.4.2.1 for details.

Also and similarly, the new `<string>` conversion functions `std::to_string` use the default `sprintf` format, and the various `std::stoul`-like functions use the C library's `strtoul`-like functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard, the C++ formatting is defined in terms of printf format
specifiers, so you can be pretty sure that simple formatters will work
the same.  There are, however, things the iostream doesn't support (and
vice versa): there's no iostream equivalent of `"% d"`, for example, and
the precision specification is ignored when outputting a string
(probably because iostream doesn't know whether the string would be part
of the format string, or correspond to a `"%s"`).

Also, don't forget that all of the format options except width are
sticky; you should save them, and restore them when you've formatted the
element which needs them.

Answer (score 0):

Let say that for that case the answer is yes, I wouldn't trust it to be the same for all cases, especially with the pains of making all the alignments right.

Did you consider [Boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/index.html)?

Something like `return boost::str(boost::format("%ld") % l);` should work
and will provide for an easier migration path.  Though differences do exist.

Comment: Boost is forbidden in my environment (don't ask...)

Comment: @AShelly ok, not asking, but I will ask if the end purpose for this task is to avoid the problem of never knowing if you have a big enough buffer allocated (or will your output be chopped).  I have dealt with that before in a way that _might_ work for you (too lazy to type if thats not going to be useful)

Comment: That's not the problem in this case - it has more to do with the fact that the massive codebase has dozens of modules containing `intToString` type functions, some based on snprintf, some on stringstream.  I'd like to consolidate, but don't want to break things.  Knowing the length is not a problem - it is limited by MAXINT or MAXLONG.